# Is it possible to set up SQS standard queue to be sure to process only once my messages?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

Is it possible to setup my SQS queue on AWS in order to process only once my message?

Maybe tweaking on long/short polling (is it going to have any impact on processing only once?) 
or visibilityTimeout seconds, 
or taking some best practice on my workers' application?

Or should I move definitely to a FIFO queue to be sure I have granted only once processing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQS will definitely process the message at least once but there a chance to process message more than once. Say you have a visibility timeout of 30 seconds and the consumer took 35 seconds to process the message then the message will again be available in the queue for other processes. If you don't have a problem with duplicate messages and expecting high throughput then SQS standard would be the right choice. Even you tweak with short polling or long polling you cannot guarantee that you can avoid duplication with SQS standard.

If you need to process message exactly once and if you strictly don't need any duplication then FIFO would be the right choice. Keep in mind throughput of FIFO wouldn't be that high as SQS standard. FIFO queues can support up to 300 messages per second

FIFO queues are designed to never introduce duplicate messages. However, your message producer might introduce duplicates in certain scenarios: for example, if the producer sends a message, does not receive a response, and then resends the same message. Amazon SQS APIs provide deduplication functionality that prevents your message producer from sending duplicates. Any duplicates introduced by the message producer are removed within a 5-minute deduplication interval.

Please read more about SQS standard [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/standard-queues.html)

Please read more about SQS FIFO [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/FIFO-queues.html)

Comment: Thanks, your answer confirm what I read form aws doc. Yes I need to process msgs only once. So you see visibility timeout use case as the only chance to have duplicates? Or there are other possibilities to have duplicates? How about increasing the timeout to a safe time longer than worst processing case? (wont ensure but minimize the issue)

Comment: @koalaok visibility time is one of the use cases. If you need to process only once then blindly go for SQS FIFO. I have updated a bit about FIFO queue in the answer section.

Comment: "...If the producer sends a message, does not receive a response, and then resends the same message.." why should that happen? SQS is supposed to be distributed and high available... a network issue? In any case that should not be my case.

Comment: That's how producer-consumer model or message broker works. The producer has to make sure the message has been delivered for a reliable communication. To make sure message delivered properly producer needs an acknowledgment from the consumer. It exactly same as we are acknowledging for a critical mail in real world

Comment: Does it answer your question?